# Update panel in custom web part causes full page refresh on Safari

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server

I'm working on a custom web part which contains an ASP.NET update panel. When I click a button to refresh its content, only the content should be refreshed, not the full page. This works like a charm, except... for Safari on an Ipad. No matter what I try, I can't get it to work on Safari.

Below are the steps to reproduce the problem:

1. Create a farm solution
2. Add a visual web part (farm solution)
3. Place an update panel on the page containing a label and button
4. Add an event handler for the button click to change the label text
5. Deploy and use on a web part page layout (publishing library)
6. Test using IE, Chrome, Firefox, etc....works fine
7. Test using Safari on an iPad... full page reload after clicking the button

I expect the issue to be the same on Safari on a Mac but I've not been able to test this since I don't have a Mac at my disposal.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am having the same issue with safari on Mac. Did you get the solution? or could you share some info about it... thanks,